# postgresql same where clause for subquery and query in optimised way

Tags: postgresql

i have four tables as
**table1**

```
srno  name   cat  main_srno
0001  prod1  A    0005
0002  prod2  B    NULL
0003  prod6  Z    0002
0004  prod22 E    0005
0005  prod11 Y    NULL
```

**table2**

```
srno  date
0001  2018-01-01
0002  2018-01-02
0003  2018-02-01
0001  2018-01-02
0002  2018-01-02
```

**table3**

```
srno  date
0001  2018-01-01
0002  2018-01-02
0003  2018-02-01
0001  2018-01-02
0002  2018-01-02
```

I want some thing like this

```
SELECT A.*, 
       (SELECT string_agg(name,',') FROM table1 
        WHERE main_srno=A.srno
          AND srno NOT IN (SELECT srno FROM table2
                           WHERE date='2017-01-02'
                           UNION
                           SELECT cino FROM table3
                           WHERE date='2017-01-02'
                          )
       ) AS child 
FROM table1 AS A 
WHERE A.srno NOT IN (SELECT srno FROM table2
                     WHERE date='2017-01-02' 
                     UNION
                     SELECT cino FROM table3
                     WHERE date='2017-01-02'
                    );
```

OUTPUT SHOULD be like this:

```
srno  name   cat  child
0005  prod11 Y    prod22,prod1
```

How can i do this in a optimised way as there may be large no of records.

Comment: 1) Do the tables have *names*? Which? 2) What is the `SELECT` supposed to do? What query do you want to formulate?

Comment: The result set  you've shown and the query you were trying don't seem to correlate and i'm finding it difficult what you want. The problem is that although you have shown the sample data and expected output, lack of more examples and basic explanation of the result set is not helping us. So, edit your question and add few more sample rows in expected o/p and explain a bit about it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query to use a CTE and a self join and change the `NOT IN` clause into two `NOT EXTSTS` clauses:

```
WITH cte AS
   (SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT table2.srno FROM table2
                      WHERE table2.srno = a.srno
                      AND table2.date = '2017-01-02')
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT table3.srno FROM table3
                      WHERE table3.srno = a.srno
                      AND table3.date = '2017-01-02')
   )
SELECT a.*, string_agg(b.name,',')
FROM cte a
   LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.srno = b.main_srno;
```

Add indexes on the tables that support the antijoin (it depends on the execution plan which ones are best).